# Ways to speed up table refresh in Excel

Tags: excel, refresh

Every day I download a table of customer and product combinations into an Excel table from a local SQL server. In Excel I have a total of 294 calculated columns performing calculations against the downloaded data (14 columns each day for the next 21 days = 294). Consistently I have discovered for the first refresh on any given day the file takes 5-10 mins to refresh and recalculate whereas any subsequent refreshes take less than 1 minute.

From reading some microsoft documentation, faster refresh times can usually be expected on second and subsequent refreshes because excel optimises the calculation chain with each subsequent calculation.

My question is whether anyone can suggest a way of forcing Excel to store the optimised calculation chain sequence so that it does not need to start from scratch every time excel is opened so that my refresh times can stay less than 1 minute.

Any suggestions are welcome.

I have attempted to execute both Application.CalculateFullRebuild and Application.CalculateFull prior to beginning the data refresh but have not found them to make a noticeable difference. I have also spent a fair bit of time refining my formulas using the usual techniques and, while they're maybe not entirely perfect, I can safely say there's not a lot else I can do to refine the formulas further.

Comment: Do you regret taking 15 minutes when you want to predict the future for 21 days? :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are changing some parameters having SQL data loaded to recalculate the result. Otherwise, I can't understand meaning of refreshing. In this scenario the described behavior is expected, which can't be bypassed. Evidently the main amount of calculation is dependent from SQL data and only some of calculations is affected by changed parameters.

You need to think how to improve your formulas to make calculations performant.

Or I didn't get your question at all?

Comment: rotabor thanks for your comments. Relevant customer and SKU combinations change every day requiring the table to be rebuilt. Once the combinations are downloaded my table performs calculations of inventory balances and other metrics out to 21 days. As I said I've spent a lot of time refining the formulas and don't believe anything else significant can be done there. Interestingly, the customer and SKU combos only take a few seconds to download, indicating it's the calculation chain in the calculated columns that takes time to build. Any tips ?